# Best way of sharing key value pairs in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-sharing

When I tried passing a map of string pairs I felt like too much of my code was hard coded (strings used as keys) and not really elegant.
That's why I'd like to ask if there is a best practice when wishing to share a map.

## What I've tried

### Map with hard coded strings

Creation:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> GetDataAsMap(){
    std::map<std::string, std::string> data;
    data["id"] = ReadProperty("id");
    ...
    return data;
}
```

Consumption:

```
auto dataMap = GetDataAsMap();
int id = dataMap["id"];
```

Issues:

- Hard coded strings
- Easy to introduce typos that won't be detected at compile time
- The consumer has to know what keys will be present (i.e. handle optional values)

### Map with hard coded strings but also pass the used keys

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> GetDataAsMap(std::set<std::string>& keys){
    std::map<std::string, std::string> data;
    data["id"] = ReadProperty("id");
    keys.insert("id");
    ...
    return data;
}
```

Here I can iterate over the keys in case I only need to show the data to the user but other than that not much is won

### Map with enum values as keys

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> GetDataAsMap(){
    std::map<std::string, std::string> data;
    data[Keys::ID] = ReadProperty("id");
    ...
    return data;
}
```

- Fixes the issue with the typos
- Still has issues when some of the values are optional
- No elegant way (to my knowledge) to get string representation of enums i.e. to show in a table

### Question

Is there any best practice or way to go that is better than what I've tried here?

Comment: err... a class?

Comment: You could read the key/value pairs from a file.

Comment: it depends on your constraints. btw "The consumer has to know what keys" is not true, the caller can iterate the map entries to see what keys are there

Comment: btw it is tempting to use `operator[]` for queries and for inserting, but note that it is most of the time doing more than what you want, eg it will create an element if there is none already for the passed key. Only if you use `find` / `insert` you can know if there was an entry present before the call

Comment: `std::map` an unordered is usually a better choice. `auto dataMap = GetDataAsMap();` copying maps around is woefully inefficient.

Comment: @n.m. "*copying maps around is woefully inefficient*" - not when using C++11 move sematics, (N)RVO, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You have a map somewhere inside GetDataAsMap and you have a map outside GetDataAsMap. That's two maps. There's at least one copy. Well if you every time create a single-use map inside GetDataAsMap, you can avoid copying, but you waste even more resources on map creation. Lose-lose.

Comment: @n.m. in the example provided, (N)RVO (also known as [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)) should be optimizing the return of `data` to avoid unnecessary copies, constructing the caller's `dataMap` directly, which is especially useful when move semantics are implemented (which `std::map` does)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think I understand your reasoning. RVO will only matter if you call GetDataAsMap once, otherwise you are wasting resources on map construction every time (either on copying or on building from scratch, doesn't matter). I didn't assume it is called only once.

Comment: @n.m. neither was I. This wasn't a question about how to create only one `map` object for the lifetime of the app (use a singleton for that). I was merely addressing your comment that "*copying maps around is woefully inefficient*", which is true only if you let it be, but is not really an issue when move semantics are used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Let's try again. If you don't *copy* a map every time you call a function, you create a *new* map every time you call a function, which is even worse. I don't think I can express myself any better than that.

Comment: @n.m. "*Let's try again*" - let's not

Comment: @RemyLebeau great

Answer (score 1):

Take the values of the map and unpack them into a struct. Optional values can be expressed using either [boost::optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) in c++17.